# Why do I see hidden DOM elements on refresh?

Tags: angular, typescript

On refreshing my webpage I see my DOM elements that should be hidden for split second before actual state of my webpage loads.why could that be happening?

Am hiding DOM elements using simple ngIf.

Angular 8 version.

```
   <div *ngIf="!callInProgress">
        <span class="earned" tabindex="0">{{ earned }}</span>

        <span class="earned-amount" tabindex="0">{{ amount }}</span>

        <span class="account" tabindex="0"
          >{{ cashbackAcc }}
          
      </div>
```

Comment: You are going to have to post some code if you want help.

Comment: Could you add the relevant code of the ngIf in the question ?

Comment: maybe you are changing the condition after angular renders DOM elements.

Comment: Please provide your code so we can easy to know what is the problem. Please also to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I dont think it would be appropriate to put up code so i didnt , let me jot down a example below,<div *ngIf="boolean condition">DOM object </div>

Comment: why not give value by defect when declare the variable?:`callInProgress:boolean=true;`

Answer (score 0):

Boolean variables are false per default. So I think you are doing modifications on this value in someplace inside your typescript file. Use *ngIf=false and check if still is not working. After that find where you are using the callInProgress variable.